# Jenkins BlueOcean missing branch and commit data?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I have a Jenkins file in the repository for `MultiBranch` pipeline.

I have a separate pipeline file for my toll gate into our integration branch. This is located in another repository. Executing it from a webhook from a BitBucket Server and both the branch and commit information is missing from BlueOcean?

Is there some way to set these values so they are picked up by BlueOcean UI?